# Alternative to GetFromClipboard in Microsoft Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, clipboard

I need an alternative for `GetFromClipboard` in Microsoft Word 365 (Windows 10).

My code using `GetFromClipboard` something like this:

```vb
Public var1
Dim MyData As DataObject
Set MyData = New DataObject
Dim var1 As String  

' extra code that locates text and selects it’
Selection.Copy
MyData.GetFromClipboard
var1 = MyData.GetText(1)
```

I was able to read var1 and execute nested macros based on what was stored there and I could also paste the contents or use TypeText to insert the contents into a document.

This method worked for several years. Now some of my client users are getting a consistent error message:

> DataObject:GetFromClipboard OpenClipboard Failed.

At first, it might read the first 25 times the code appears but stop on the 26th. For a while, the users could restart the macro and the line of code would work and the entire process would run. Then 2-3 tries were needed. Each time the error message came up, it stopped on a different instance of the `GetFromClipboard` line. Now the macro refuses to pass the first `GetFromClipboard` line, and throws the error message.

One computer in the firm can run these macros and it does not give an error.  Everyone in the office has to sit at this one computer to run these macros.  It is using the same normal.dotm, has the same operating system.

I need an alternative with the key feature being that the stored variable must be available in nested macros or called macros. Most of the options I tried store the contents of the variable as long as that macro is running. It will not remember it in a macro that is nested or called.

I found a posting that said to use `Static` (with a clear example). Unless I'm coding it wrong, it doesn't work.

How can I copy text, store the text in a variable, and access the contents of that variable in other macros called by the main macro?

I tried `Static`, `PutInClipboard`, several other options that work in Excel, but not Word.

Comment: May I know why do you have to use clipboard? How about `var1 = Selection.Range.Text` ?

Comment: I need to use the contents of the variable across several macros (nested and called) and be able to close and open documents in Word (not Excel workbooks). All of the other options I have tried hold the variable while that macro is running and/or while a particular document is open. The Clipboard worked perfectly in the past, but has stopped working.  If you have a bit of sample code besides that one line that I can try, I'd be delighted to find out it works.

Answer (score 0):

- Clipboard is not a reliable solution. Users' operation or other software might destroy the content on clipboard.
- I recommend storing the value in the Windows registry rather than the clipboard. The advantage is that you can still access it even after a reboot.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub WriteRegistry()
    Dim KeyName As String
    Dim StrValue As String
    Const APP_NAME = "MyApp" ' modify as needed
    Const SECTION = "Word"
    KeyName = "WordVar"
    StrValue = "**This is a test string.**"
    SaveSetting APP_NAME, SECTION, KeyName, StrValue
    MsgBox "Text successfully stored in the registry.", vbInformation
End Sub

Sub ReadRegistry()
    Dim KeyName As String
    Dim StrValue As String
    Const APP_NAME = "MyApp"
    Const SECTION = "Word"
    KeyName = "WordVar"
    StrValue = GetSetting(APP_NAME, SECTION, KeyName)
    MsgBox "Retrieved Text: " & StrValue, vbInformation
End Sub

Sub RemoveRegistry()
    Const APP_NAME = "MyApp"
    Const SECTION = "Word"
    DeleteSetting APP_NAME, SECTION
    MsgBox "Remove it from the registry.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [SaveSetting statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/savesetting-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1020904)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [GetSetting function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getsetting-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1020902)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

> [DeleteSetting statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/deletesetting-statement?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1020901)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

[image]

Comment: These are all good possibilities I have not tried.  I will work on them today and see if I can get the result I need.  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

This Function uses the Windows API to access the contents of the clipboard and returns it as a String (This function only works if the contents can be represented as a string - it checks if that's the case so even if the contents is not a string there's not gonna be an error, it will just return an empty string)

The API declarations will work on both 32bit and 64bit versions of Office.

Edit: Only works for VBA 7 (for earlier versions the declarations would have to be adjusted - could be done with conditional compilation if the code needs to work on both VBA 7 and earlier versions)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal uFormat As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32" (ByVal uFormat As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1 As LongPtr, ByVal lpString2 As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Private Enum ClipboardFormats
    CF_TEXT = 1&
    CF_OEMTEXT = 7&
    CF_UNICODETEXT = 13&
End Enum

Public Function getText() As String
    Dim hClip As LongPtr
    Dim pLock As LongPtr
    Dim uniText As String
    Dim size As Long
    
    If OpenClipboard(0&) = 0 Then Exit Function
    If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(ClipboardFormats.CF_UNICODETEXT) <> 0 Then
        hClip = GetClipboardData(ClipboardFormats.CF_UNICODETEXT)
        If Not IsEmpty(hClip) Then
            pLock = GlobalLock(hClip)
            If pLock Then
                size = GlobalSize(hClip)
                uniText = String$(size \ 2& - 1&, vbNullChar)
                lstrcpy StrPtr(uniText), pLock
                GlobalUnlock hClip
            End If
            getText = Replace(uniText, vbNullChar, "")
        End If
    End If
    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

You would use this as follows:

```
Sub main()
    var1 = getText()
End Sub
```